# Anyway to remove the 0 on the y-axis in Plotly R graph?

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly

I have this simple graphic I am making with plotly.

```
library(plotly)
fig <- plot_ly(x = ~rnorm(50), type = "histogram")

fig
```

This is the output.

[image]

But my goal is this - no 0 on the y-axis.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by setting the `tickvals` and `ticktext` manually via layout options. Note that you have to se `tickmode="array"`. One drawback is that this adds some additional space on the left and the top so that you have to additionally set the margins manually.

```r
library(plotly)

set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(50)
fig <- plot_ly(x = ~x, type = "histogram")

fig %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(
    tickvals = as.list(seq(0, 20, 2)),
    ticktext = as.list(c("", seq(2, 20, 2))),
    tickmode = "array"
  ), margin = list(l = 2, t = 2))
```

[image]