# Plotly Labelling a subset of the ticks. Problem using ticktext

Tags: r, layout, plotly, r-plotly, yaxis

I am trying to generate a plot where only some of the ticks on the vertical axis are labeled. This is because I want to have a thick grid in the background but prefer the y axis to not be overcrowded. I tried to achieve this with ticktext and so far I have generated two results that are both unsatisfactory. Here is a minimal example:

```
library(plotly)
mydata<- data.frame(myx = 1:10, myy = 1:10)
mygrid<- 0:11
mytext_n<- c(0, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, 9, NA, NA)
mytext<- c("0", "", "", "3", "", "", "6", "", "", "9", "", "")

plot_ly(mydata, x = ~myx) %>% add_trace(type = "scatter", y = ~myy, mode = "lines") %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(tickvals = mygrid, ticktext = mytext_n))
plot_ly(mydata, x = ~myx) %>% add_trace(type = "scatter", y = ~myy, mode = "lines") %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(tickvals = mygrid, ticktext = mytext))
```

The problem is that when the text vector is numeric, it adds the text "null" to the empty spots. When it is a character, it adds an enormous white space left of the chart. Nothing changes if I specify `tickmode = "array"`.

My objective is to have grids without labels. If you don't have a solution to the problem with the above code, perhaps you have an alternative method to achieve this.

Comment: I encountered the same issue when answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68186525/12993861) question. My fix for the white space issue was to set the margins manually.

Comment: Similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38102118/12505251

Comment: Indeed @MartinGal, I used that answer to solve my problem. I will add an answer in a bit. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @stefan I did try setting margins but it didn't work. Since I was improvising (I tried, among other things, to set negative margin values), I will try imitating your example see if it works. Thanks!